# Foursquare Java SDK: 405 "This endpoint only supports GET"

Tags: java, android, foursquare

I have implemented a foursquare-api-java SDK in my Android app.

Sending the sample request  described in https://code.google.com/p/foursquare-api-java/wiki/BasicUsage - it all works in the emulator. It breaks as soon as I try it on the phone, returning 405 "This endpoint only supports GET" error.

Has anyone ran into the same problem? Any ideas?

Comment: Here I have the issue in the emulator but not on the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem in Android ICS.

Check this:
http://code.google.com/p/foursquare-api-java/issues/detail?id=66

The error was fixed by removing *setDoOutput(true)* from **DefaultIOHandler.java** class.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are doing but most functions are only available as GET. User/self is an example.

Hope this helps. Just change it to Get request instead of Post